Action Launcher Action remains blank with spinner
I have created an Action that creates a new task. With System Administrator it works perfectly, but with a profile that I created it does not work. It's clearly a permissions issue. I have given it the permissions that the "Help" tells me but I still can't get it to work.
I have also given permission to the "Task" object.
Perhaps there is some other permission that is necessary, I would appreciate the help.

